# Playing audio files continously from a listview, without user click on the listitem

Tags: android, audio

I have a list of audio files in a directory in sdcard. I have derived the files in a listview, now I want to play the files continuously, without user click on the listitem. Any suggestion please

Comment: If you don't want the users to click on the item, why the hell did you put them in a listview?

Comment: Then suggest me how to play the whole files as a single file without a pause. I can use OncompletionListener, but there will be a pause between the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

```
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            if (currentIx < playListLength - 1) {

                currentIx++;



                mp.reset();
                // Change Current Song here using the set data source method and whatever else must change

                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. But there will be a little pause between the files, if OnCompletionListener is used. I need to play the file as a single file without a pause.

Answer (score 0):

when ever a audio is playing callbacks are automatically called.
if the file completely played **OnCompletionListener** call back is called.you can again start the next file in that method.

Comment: Thanks. But there will be a little pause between the files, if OnCompletionListener is used. I need to play the file as a single file without a pause.

Answer (score 0):

To play songs continuously Have a look on the following URL

http://coderzheaven.com/index.php/2011/02/play-all-songs-from-your-raw-directory-in-android-continuously/

Thanks
Deepak